# How to use table view to show different content according to the button pressed like Instagram

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, tableview

Hi I'm a new comer to swift.

Is it better to use UICollectionView or UITableviewcell ?

I tried to link buttons to the UIview but I couldn't

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place your `buttons` outside the whole `UITableView stuff`, for example in a `UIToolBar` at top/bottom of the table, and simply create an `IBAction` per each button that reloads the content of the `UITableView` with different informations.

Basically change the data you pass to the manager to fill in the table and reload.

Comment: please if you can help with sample code how to connect button to view that reload date, I'll be thankful